# Unable to align ticks with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Working with one bar chart with d3.js I am unable to align ticks in x axis with bars.

[image: Ticks are bad aligned in center area of X axis]

In left and right verges the ticks are ok, but not in the middle.
Here is the code:

```
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%e %b");
var height = 325;
var xTimeScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 2].date), 1)])
        .range([30, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xTimeScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(d3.time.days, .1)
        .tickFormat(formatDate);

chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xaxis axis") 
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

chart.selectAll(".xaxis text") 
        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height * -2 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-45)";});
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6GRS/) updated with [chrtan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182965/chrtan) suggestions.
My problem now is to align text with the center of bar and not in left.

Comment: Can you please setup a jsFiddle showing your problem?

Comment: How are you generating the bars?

Comment: jsFiddle has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your graph, you lost a bar's worth of space. If all the bars are supposed to be left-aligned against a tick, that final bar you have should be to the right of the January 31st tick.

You might need to add the February 1st tick by perhaps changing the [data.length - 2] to [data.length - 1] in the domain() for your xTimeScale.

Then for display purposes, you could probably remove the last tick axis text with:

```
d3.select(chart.selectAll(".xaxis text")[0].pop()).remove();
```

The inner selectAll should get the array containing your xAxis tick texts and then pop the very last tick. This last tick should then be removed by the outer select.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem with ticks but now the text is not down the bar; it is in the same place than tick (left). It is any way to have text just down the bar? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Julián: In the piece of code where you rotate the text, you can translate the text further to the right by adding the offset of the axis to the x portion of the translate. (I used 30 in this example.)      `chart.selectAll(".xaxis text") // select all the text elements for the xaxis      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + (this.getBBox().height * -2 + 30) + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-45)";})`

Answer (score 0):

An example with an auto time ticks with d3.js

```
// set domain for axis
var x_domain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return new Date(d.date); });
//format date
var  date_format = d3.time.format('%Y %B');

var vis = d3.select("#graph")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.data; })]).nice()
    .range([height - padding, padding]); 
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(x_domain)
    .range([padding, width - padding]);
// define the y axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("left")
    .scale(yScale);
// define the x axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("bottom")
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat(date_format);
// draw y axis with labels and move in from the size by the amount of padding
vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+padding+",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
// draw x axis with labels and move to the bottom of the chart area
vis.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xaxis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// and set data in graph...
```

a great example : http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3061203